# Paste into a textfield under android does not work

Tags: android, codenameone, copy-paste

I've got one problem with paste into a textfield in an codenameone app with android 4.1.1 and also 4.3: When I tip on the cursor the context-menu "paste" is shown - but very short and disappears then. I have no chance to paste a text in a textfield.
Under iOS I have no problem with it.

Do you have any idea?

Kind regards
Klaus

Can be reproduced with an empty App like this:

```
public void start()
{
    if (current != null)
    {
        current.show();
        return;
    }

    Form hi = new Form("Hi World");
    hi.setScrollableY(true);
    hi.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    TextField tmpTextField = new TextField();

    Container tmpInnerContainer = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    tmpInnerContainer.add(tmpTextField);

    hi.add(tmpInnerContainer);

    tmpTextField.setText("Textfield with a very long Text in it, Textfield with a very long Text in it");

    hi.show();
}
```

Comment: I just tried this in an app I built and it worked well. Is there anything special you are doing in this app?

Comment: No - nothing special. I could reproduce this behavior in an empty app (just one textfield in a form) on an Huawei Y300-0100 with Android 4.1.1

Comment: If the only thing that reproduces this is an old Android device that might be hard to debug. Can you please file an issue and mention that this is only happening with that device/OS version. If there is a specific 3rd party keyboard installed please also mention that.

Comment: OK - I created an issue on github

Comment: Reference https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2147